# Problem when comparing two objects in method assertEquals

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just learning php and I ran into a problem
When I try to compare, I get the same error about the array.
*Object (...) does not match expected type "array".*

```php
public function testShow() {
        $item = Item::factory()->create();

        $response = $this->json('GET', "api/items/$item->id");

        $response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonStructure([
               'id',
               'title',
               'content',
               'is_important',
               'created_at',
               'updated_at'
            ]);

        $receivedItem = $response->decodeResponseJson();


        $this->assertEquals($item->toArray(), $receivedItem); // swears here
    }
```

Tried it directly

```php
$this->assertEquals($item, $this->object->decodeResponseJson())
```

Comment: Alternatively, convert the object to an array before comparing
    $this->assertEquals($item->toArray(), json_decode(json_encode($receivedItem), true));

Comment: What does `decodeResponseJson()` return (the data type specifically)

Comment: @NigelRen , validate and return the decoded response JSON
In general, it returns me JSON in an array.

Comment: @KarlHill , the problem is not with the second attribute, but with the first. It is returned as an object and is not converted to an array.

Comment: Try `echo gettype($this->object->decodeResponseJson());` to see what it says.

Comment: @NigelRen I did it a little differently, but both objects.
`Log::info(gettype($receivedItem)); 
 Log::info(gettype($item));`
`[2023-11-25 19:58:13] testing.INFO: object  
[2023-11-25 19:58:13] testing.INFO: object  `